# How to track changes in files stored in Oracle Berkeley DB XML

Tags: xml, version-control, clearcase, berkeley-db

I am wondering how it is possible to track the modifications made on XML files stored in a Berkeley DB XML.

e.g.

We have many XML files that store some parameters. We intent to store them in Berkeley DB XML.

But we want to be able to track changes between two versions of the same XML file stored in the Berkeley DB XML using version control tool (Clearcase, svn, ...)

Does it possible ? Version control of the Berkeley DB XML is an option ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to track any text file in a source control tool, and ClearCase has an xml type manager which facilitates version comparison.

The [OP Sébastien Sénégas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1728047/sebastien-senegas) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857188/how-to-track-changes-in-files-stored-in-oracle-berkeley-db-xml#comment17401997_12857549):

> the question is to track changes once the XML file is stored into Berkeley DataBase XML

There is nothing in SVN or ClearCase which would allows to natively track a Berkeley DataBase: those tools track any source file, without distinction.

So unless you symlink your xml files from your  Berkeley DataBase  to a ClearCase snapshot view, you wouldn't benefit from versioning.

Comment: Yes, I know this but the question is to track changes once the XML file is stored into Berkeley DataBase XML

Comment: @SébastienSénégas I have edited the answer to address your specific question

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to architect that kind of change management yourself into the application requiring the change management. Or, if you're looking for a more forensic approach, you can dig through the transaction logs.